# Search in a document library using calculated column

Tags: 2013, document-library, custom-list, calculated-column

I have a list, where I try to use the Calculated column to retrieve data from a document library.

This is what I want to accomplish:
In my list, I have a column named "doc_id". I want to use this unique ID to search in my document library for the corresponding "doc_id". If it matches, I want to link the file to my calulated column

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated Columns cannot look outside of the current list item. They cannot reference a Lookup Column. You may need to look into workflows.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, sad to hear that it was not possible via the calculated column. I have not worked with workflow before, but I'll take a look at it! thanks